# Infinispan + Hibernate L2 Cache + JGroups causing ReadWriteKeyCommand error

Tags: hibernate, infinispan, jgroups

I've got a stand-alone application leveraging the following stack:
Hibernate 5.6
Infinispan 13.0.15
JGroups 4.2.22

I'm using Infinispan as a second level cache for Hibernate -- I've noticed that when I start up my second application node I get the following error:

ISPN000136: Error executing command ReadWriteKeyCommand on Cache 'clientDeviceNotificationTimeRangeCache', writing keys [com.xxx.ClientDeviceNotificationTimeRangeVO#ClientDeviceNotificationTimeRangePrimaryKey [clientId=5041, dayOfWeek=1]]|
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

This causes the primary node to throw an accompanying error:

org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 0 milliseconds for key com.xxx.ClientDeviceNotificationTimeRangeVO#ClientDeviceNotificationTimeRangePrimaryKey [clientId=5041, dayOfWeek=5] and requestor CommandInvocation:localhost-54954:4420. Lock is held by null

It seems like the cache is replicating objects to the secondary node before the secondary node is actually fully up and available -- strangely this worked perfectly fine in the 8.0 series .. any obvious thing I might be overlooking here? some new setting or flag I am omitting? the only other oddity I can see here is what is setting a 0 milliseconds lock timeout for a key? that doesn't seem right ..

Comment: i attempted to alter the locking level to the 8.0 default of READ_COMMITTED but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue either.

Comment: this issue actually started in 10.x, i reverted the library to version 10.0 and I get the same results there, 9.0 works fine fwiw